# ReactJS react-show-more-text `lines` props not working

Tags: reactjs

**react-show-more-text** *lines={3}* props not working. I already set `<td>` and `<th>` - maxWidth,
Here is my Code:

```
    <td style={{ maxWidth: 210 }}>
      <ShowMoreText
        lines={3}
        more="Show more"
        less="Show less"
        onClick={this.executeOnClick}
        expanded={false}
        width={200}
      >
        {this.props.row.Data}
      </ShowMoreText>
    </td>
```

[please here is image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O2Tt.png)